# Java iterate over generics

Tags: java, loops, generics

Hey Guys I'm relativly new to Java and I'm struggling a bit with the use of generics.
Basically I want to iterate over an collection of transitions which are stored in a Set-class.  If I create an Instance of the Set-class I do not face any problems, but I want to iterate over the Transitions stored in the FA-class which causes some trouble(cannot convert Object to Transition).There must be some Issue with the code but I'm not able to find it :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FA fa = new FA( new Set<String>("A", "B", "C"),
                     "A", 
                     new Set<Transition>(new Transition("A", 1, "B"),
                                        new Transition( "B",2,"C")),
                                        new Set<String>("C") );

    Set<Transition> t=new Set();
    t.add(new Transition("A", 1, "B"));

    for (Transition transition : t) {   
        //Works as intended
    }

   //error cannot convert Object to Transition
    for (Transition transition : fa.Transitions) {  
        //not working
    }
```

**Fa-class:**

```
public class FA<T>
{
    public Set<T>         States;
    public T            StartState;
    public Set<Transition>         Transitions;
    public Set<T>         FinalState;

    public FA(){}

    public FA( Set<T> states, T startstate, Set<Transition> transitions, Set<T> finalstate) {

      States     = states;
      StartState = startstate;
      Transitions= transitions; 
      FinalState = finalstate ;
    }
}
```

**Set-class:**

```
 public class Set<T> implements Iterable<T>
 {

  private ArrayList<T> Menge=new ArrayList<T>(); 

  public Set( T ... menge ) {   
    for( int i=0; i < menge.length; i++ ) {     
        Menge.add((T) menge[i] );
    }
  }

public int count() {
    return Menge.size();
}

public T get(int i) {
    return (T)Menge.get(i);
}

public void add(T i) {
            Menge.add((T)i);

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Menge.toString();
}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Menge.iterator();
 }
}
```

**Transition-class:**

```
 public class Transition<T>
 {
  private T  Source;
  private T Label;
  private T  Target;

 public Transition( T source, T label, T target ) {
    Source = source;
    Label  = label ;
    Target = target;
 }

 public T get(int i)
 {
    if(i==1)return Source;
    if(i==2)return Label;
    return Source;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return Source.toString() + " - " + Label.toString() + " -> " + Target.toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: fa.Transition or fa.TransitionS ?

Comment: In your first code block, you reference fa.transition which does not exist.

Comment: Transitions sorry ;) but does not fix the error

Comment: Is there any reason you're making `Transition` a generic class, then not specifying the types it should hold when you create `Transition` objects?  The way you're using Transition now makes Source, Label, and Target all `Object` types.

Comment: I should accept Int and String as input

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of fa is wrong, it should be:

```
FA<Transition> fa = new FA<>( new Set<String>("A", "B", "C"),
                     "A", 
                     new Set<Transition>(new Transition("A", 1, "B"),
                                        new Transition( "B",2,"C")),
                                        new Set<String>("C") );
```

And btw there are a few other errors in generic instantiation, I'd suggest you to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast response, your solution seems to work. I guess I have to read more about generics -.-